# Errors in Umbraco macro

Tags: xslt, macros, umbraco, loading

I have some issues loading the macro scripts in both backend and front end. On frontend its showing the error "Error loading MacroEngine script (file: filename.cshtml)"
and on backend It says 
"Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find a part of the path 'E:\web\site\htdocs\xslt\'. " 
see the attached images.

[image: When clicked on any macro in backend of Umbraco]

[image: Error shown when clicked on Umbraco folder in backed of Umbraco]

[image: This is the error I got on frontend of the site]

Can anyone please help me how to fix these issues.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the xslt folder exist? Also remember to grant read/write access to your iis role (normally Network Service) on the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by emptying app_data/temp/ExmineIndex folder and republishing the whole site.
Shared it coz someone else may get the same issue.